# Tikz Hierarchical Chart - Branching

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts

I am trying to get Rachel Brown all on one line, and below Rachel Brown - three branches that say Mary Brown, Laura Brown and Emma Brown. I am also trying to get ages to show below each name, for example directly below Hannah Brown it needs to say (Age: 23), etc. Many Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
-- +(0,-8pt)
-| (\tikzchildnode)}},
blank/.style={draw=none}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix
{
\node{\Tree 
 [.{Hannah Brown}
  [.Rachel Brown ]]};\\
};           
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If not, what is missing?

Answer (score 5):

To get `Rachel Brown` in one line, do as with Hannah, and add braces (`{}`). If you add `every tree node/.style={align=center}` you can use `\\`  to add linebreaks in a node, and then you can use `Rachel Brown\\Age: 23` to place the age below the name. To get three branches you need to write something like `[ .root [ .{first branch}] [ .{second branch} ] [ .{third branch} ] ]`. Note that each branch is within the pair of brackets where the root is defined.

To properly align the middle branch, add `minimum width=\widthof{Hannah Brown}` to the `every tree node` style. You can also use a specific length (e.g. 
3cm) instead of `\widthof{the longest name in the family}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
-- +(0,-8pt)
-| (\tikzchildnode)}},
blank/.style={draw=none},
level distance=45pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={align=center,minimum width=\widthof{Hannah Brown}}]
\Tree 
 [ .{Hannah Brown}
   [ .{Rachel Brown\\Age: 23} 
     [ .{Mary Brown\\Age: 1} ]
     [ .{Laura Brown\\Age: 2} ]
     [ .{Emma Brown\\Age: 3} ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```