# Trees with nodes consisting of multiple lines

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

I want to draw a tree but I want the nodes to be able to have multiple lines and specific width. I have searched about trees but all of them consist of a single line in each node. From what I have found Tikz seems nice but I have no idea about tree packages. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: RelatedL http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169796/tikz-hierarchical-chart-branching/169806#169806

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176649/39222 for very fancy multi-line nodes.

Comment: I had already see those answers but they didn't help me

Comment: Why not? You said you couldn't find any examples with multiline nodes and fixed width. @TorbjørnT. pointed you to an answer showing how to use multiple lines in tree nodes. I pointed you to one which uses multiple lines and specifies the width of nodes. Since those are just the things you said you couldn't find, I don't understand why they didn't help. If you are still having trouble, please ask a new question which includes a complete, small document which people can compile and which demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: @cfr I will study those examples thoroughly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The multiline nodes require `align` option (`align=center`, `align=left` or similar).

Specific width of the nodes is specified in `minimum width`, you can use `pt` or `em` units or any other unit of your liking (read on the LaTeX units).

Example: `minimum width=14em`

HTH